# mouse and keyboard automaticlly not working

Tags: openelec

Once I get to the   questions, the mouse and keyboard do not work. 
What do I do??? We have tried taking out the power but that is not helping.

Comment: Are your mouse/keyboard on the verified list? http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals Do they work with Rasbian instead of OpenELEC?

Comment: might help to tell us what's the model/maker of your keyboard/mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Step one: check your power. Too many Pi users accept that the power they are using works fine, when really its right on the edge of what the Pi can handle.
[Test your power](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems)

Step two: plug keyboard in before powering on the Pi, does it work?

Step three: plug in mouse before powering on the Pi, does it work?

If any do not work and your sure you completed step one: then try a USB hub.

I mention all those steps from bitter experience, with bad power supplies, good power supplies but bad cables, heavy power usage keyboards(never had a problem with mice).